# Getting Data using the Zend Framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I've setup a page so that when you click on a link it will go to the specific action followed by the id of what was clicked on.

For instance, if I had a list of albums and clicked play on an album with an id of 2 it would go to `www.mysite/albums/play/2`.

I have this working as I would like it, however, when I'm in the `playAction()` method in the controller, how can I get the ID of the specific album I chose?

Comment: Hi can you post your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID can be found by adding this line to the controller:

```
$id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
```